# how to avoid thread.sleep before open a url

Tags: selenium-webdriver

After login a webpage i want to open another url.if i give implicitwait it didnot open the url

```
driver.get("https://www.naukri.com/nlogin/login");
}

@Test(priority=1)
public void naukriTest() throws InterruptedException{

    driver.findElement(By.id("usernameField")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("passwordField")).sendKeys("xyz");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='waves-effect waves-light btn-large btn-block btn-bold blue-btn']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.get("https://careernavigator.naukri.com/careers-in-mahindra-and-mahindra-financial-services-0");
```

i want to avoid that thread.sleep

Comment: plz someone help...if i give implicit wait it didnot open

Comment: Not sure if those were real but please be careful about publishing the actual credentials.

Comment: Why are you waiting 5 seconds before loading another URL?  I don't see anywhere that an implicit wait would help.  What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: it didnt give any error .but it didn't open second url

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks..next time i will take care for it

Comment: Why didn't it open the second URL? Was there an error thrown, etc.?

Comment: @jeffC no it didnot showing any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly; you want to finish login and then open the second URL.

I would put in an explicit wait on the "just logged in" element. Something like, waiting for the element that holds "Welcome back, abc!" or any element that changes after login.

Comment: yes i want to open second url only after log in...because without login if i open second url this one didnt show me the whole table